# What is the group O(4)/H, where H is the center of O(4)?

Tags: lie-groups

What is the group $O(4)/H$?

Here  $O(4)$ is the group of orthogonal matrices and H is the center of $O(4)$.

Comment: It's the group of inner automorphisms of $O(4)$.

Comment: This looks a bit like homework to me (http://mathoverflow.net/faq#whatnot). What is your motivation for considering this question?

Comment: Someone can make a nice question out of nice applications of this post!

Comment: If this answer is sufficient for your purposes, why not accept it?

Answer (score 4):

This group is isomorphic to $(SO(3) \times SO(3)) \rtimes \{\pm 1\}$, as is discussed in [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/53822/in-the-quaternions-any-imaginary-unit-may-be-called-i) and its comments.  (The order two factor comes from the fact that
$O(4) = SO(4) \rtimes \{\pm 1\},$ and that $H \subset SO(4)$.)  [Added as per Scott Carnahan's comment below: The order two factor shouldn't be a direct factor, but a semi-direct factor.  I leave it as an exercise to determine its action on $SO(3) \times SO(3)$.  If someone reading this knows the correct LaTeX command for a semi-direct product, feel free to make the appropriate edit.]

Comment: Is it really a group-theoretic direct product? This seems like a situation where one should use the semidirect product symbol $\rtimes$ (and possibly specify the involution).

Comment: Dear Scott, No, of course you're correct; it's a semi-direct product.
Thanks!  Best wishes, Matthew

Comment: Added the \rtimes as needed.

Comment: Dear David, Thanks!  Regards, Matthew